# Navigation or top search bar like Myntra

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I want to make a similar search bar like [this website](http://myntra.com/) using Angularjs and Bootstrap. I have made a function which hides the first bar when scrolled and shows the second one. But when I get on the top, the second search bar is only shown.

---

How can this be done so that when we get on top, the first search bar appears?

Comment: The first bar is always in the page , but the second only comes when you scroll down , simple as that but if u want step by step code , this is the wrong website

Comment: I don't want the code, what i need is the approach. Like, at a certain point of time, the second bar appears, and then it goes away after you scroll up the page, when the static navigation appears.